# Refresh a tab after information has been chnaged

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have a tab strip using kendo for MVC. I'm trying to update the tab or reload a tab after the information has been changing.

For some reason it the reload does not work.

I have tried this using javascript:

```
var a = tabStrip= $("#summary-tabstrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
tabstrip.reload("abcxyz");
```

Tab:

```
tabstrip.Add().Text("Screening")
         .Enabled(true)
         .Content(Html.Partial("~/Views/EyeTestReport/_Screening.cshtml", new Website.Models.EyeTestReport.ScreeningViewModel(Model.VisitID)).ToHtmlString()
         ).ContentHtmlAttributes(new { @id = "abcxyz"});
```

but it does nothing apparently.

Anything I can try? If you need anything else let me know and I will post.

Comment: `tabstrip.reload("#abcxyz");` ?

Comment: The documentation on https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/methods/reload says that `reload` "Reloads TabStrip tab(s) via AJAX." Your content isn't loaded via AJAX. Thus: No reloading.

Comment: @CarstenFranke ah ok thank you